# I want to migrate my current logic app to another subscription?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have an subscription and now created a new one ,
can i migrate the current logic app to another?
If yes, then how to do it? Any help will be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WAY - 1:**

This is possible through the portal. You can navigate to your logic app's overview pane and use move beside the subscription to move from one subscription to another.

[image]

Fill out the required details as below.

[image]

**WAY - 2:**

Step - 1: Navigate to your resource group, Select the resource that you want to move across the subscriptions

Step - 2: On top right you can find Move and select Move to another Subscription.

[image]

For other ways such as powershell - [Move-AzResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/move-azresource?view=azps-8.2.0), CLI - [az resource move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-move) or rest API you can refer [Move resources - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#move).

**REFERENCES :** [Move resources between subscriptions - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/move-logic-app-resources#move-resources-between-subscriptions)